# PostgreSQL - Fail to start delegate ip address on pgpool 2

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, watchdog, pgpool, virtual-ip-address

I try to set up a pgpool server on ubuntu server and following this link : [pgpool-II Tutorial [ Watchdog ]](http://www.pgpool.net/pgpool-web/contrib_docs/watchdog/en.html).

But when I to start a pgpool service, the delegated IP doesn't start.

I have seen in a log file on syslog and got some error like this.

```
    Oct 25 08:46:25 pgpool-1 pgpool[1647]: [8-2] 2017-10-25 08:46:25: pid 1647: DETAIL:  Host:"172.16.0.42" WD Port:9000 pgpool-II port:5432 
    Oct 25 08:46:25 pgpool-1 pgpool: SIOCSIFADDR: Operation not permitted
    Oct 25 08:46:25 pgpool-1 pgpool: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
    Oct 25 08:46:25 pgpool-1 pgpool: SIOCSIFNETMASK: Operation not permitted
    Oct 25 08:46:25 pgpool-1 pgpool[1648]: [18-1] 2017-10-25 08:46:25: pid 1648: LOG:  failed to acquire the delegate IP address
    Oct 25 08:46:25 pgpool-1 pgpool[1648]: [18-2] 2017-10-25 08:46:25: pid 1648: DETAIL:  'if_up_cmd' failed
    Oct 25 08:46:25 pgpool-1 pgpool[1648]: [19-1] 2017-10-25 08:46:25: pid 1648: WARNING:  watchdog escalation failed to acquire delegate IP
```

I use ubuntu 14.04 with pgpool2 version 3.6.6-1, and watchdog version 5.31-1.

And I has configured on pgpool.conf at virtual IP setting like this.

```
# - Virtual IP control Setting -
delegate_IP = '172.16.0.201'
if_cmd_path = '/sbin'
if_up_cmd = 'ifconfig eth0:0 inet $_IP_$ netmask 255.255.0.0'
if_down_cmd = 'ifconfig eth0:0 down'
arping_path = '/usr/sbin'
arping_cmd = 'arping -U $_IP_$ -w 1'
```

Any suggestion for this? Thank you for any help.

Comment: Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like user that runs it doesn't have permission to use ifconfig.
Did you follow [those steps](http://www.pgpool.net/pgpool-web/contrib_docs/watchdog_master_slave_3.3/en.html#config_setuid) from tutorial?

> setuid configuration
>
> In watchdog process, root privilege is required to contol virtual IP.
>   You could start pgpool-II as root user. However in this tutorial,
>   Apache needs to start pgpool as apache user and control virtual IP
>   because we are using pgpoolAdmin. For this purpose, we setuid
>   if_config and arping. Also we don't want any user other than apache
>   accesses the commands because of security reason. Execute following
>   commands on each of osspc19 and osspc20 (It requires root privilege).
>
> At first, make a directory for containing ipconfig and arping which is
>   set setuid. The path is specified at ifconif_path and arping_path; in
>   this tutorial, this is /home/apache/sbin. Then give execute privilege
>   to only apache user.
>
> ```
> $ su -
> # mkdir -p /home/apache/sbin
> # chown apache:apache /home/apache/sbin
> # chmod 700 /home/apache/sbin
> ```
>
> Next, copy the original ifconfig and arping to the directory and then
>   set setuid to these.
>
> ```
> # cp /sbin/ifconfig /home/apache/sbin
> # cp /use/sbin/arping /home/apache/sbin
> # chmod 4755 /home/apache/sbin/ifconfig
> # chmod 4755 /home/apache/sbin/arping
> ```
>
> Note that explained above should be used for tutorial purpose only. In
>   the real world you'd better create setuid wrapper programs to execute
>   ifconfig and arping. This is left for your exercise.

Comment: I try to do as this steps again, but get a same result.

Answer (score 0):

(Note: this answer may help in case you run Pgpool-II servers with Watchdog in Docker containers)

I tried to setup Pgpool-II servers with Watchdog in Docker containers today, and I got almost the same error (though I did [set the SUID bit](http://www.pgpool.net/pgpool-web/contrib_docs/watchdog_master_slave/en.html#config_setuid) and even tried running Pgpool-II as the root user):

```
SIOCSIFADDR: Operation not permitted
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
SIOCSIFNETMASK: Operation not permitted
pid 88: LOG:  failed to acquire the delegate IP address
pid 88: DETAIL:  'if_up_cmd' failed
pid 88: WARNING:  watchdog escalation failed to acquire delegate IP
```

Later I found that it was because the container did not have the privilege to change its network configurations, by default by design.

I then ran my Pgpool-II Docker containers in the privileged mode as shown below:

```
pgpool1:
    privileged: true
    image: postdock/pgpool:latest-pgpool36
    ...
```

The error is gone and the virtual IP is set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved by the following method.

Make a directory for containing ipconfig and arping. Then give execute privilege to only non-root user.

```
$mkdir /var/lib/pgsql/sbin
$chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/pgsql/sbin
$cp /sbin/ip /var/lib/pgsql/sbin
$cp /sbin/arping /var/lib/pgsql/sbin
```

Run visudo, which safely edits the sudoers file:

```
$visudo
```

Then add an entry like this in sudoers file:

```
postgres ALL = NOPASSWD: /var/lib/pgsql/sbin/ip *, /var/lib/pgsql/sbin/arping *
```

Next, create bash files(ipadd.sh,ipdel.sh,arping.sh) to run ip and arping commands with sudo.

```
$cat /var/lib/pgsql/sbin/ipadd.sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo /var/lib/pgsql/sbin/ip addr add $1/24 dev eth1 label eth1:0

$cat /var/lib/pgsql/sbin/ipdel.sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo /var/lib/pgsql/sbin/ip addr del $1/24 dev eth1

$cat /var/lib/pgsql/sbin/arping.sh
#!/bin/bash
sudo /var/lib/pgsql/sbin/arping -U $1 -w 1 -I eth1

$chmod 755 /var/lib/pgsql/sbin/*
$chown postgres:postgres /var/lib/pgsql/sbin/*
```

Add an entry like this in pgpool.conf:

```
delegate_IP = '10.10.10.62'
if_up_cmd = 'ipadd.sh $_IP_$'
if_down_cmd = 'ipdel.sh $_IP_$'
arping_cmd = 'arping.sh $_IP_$'
if_cmd_path = '/var/lib/pgsql/sbin'
arping_path = '/var/lib/pgsql/sbin'
```

Then restart the pgpool service. Ignore the warning you can see as follows.

> WARNING: checking setuid bit of if_up_cmd
>   DETAIL: ifup[/var/lib/pgsql/sbin/ipadd.sh] doesn't have setuid bit
>   WARNING: checking setuid bit of if_down_cmd
>   DETAIL: ifdown[/var/lib/pgsql/sbin/ipdel.sh] doesn't have setuid bit
>   WARNING: checking setuid bit of arping command
>   DETAIL: arping[/var/lib/pgsql/sbin/arping.sh] doesn't have setuid bit

Stop and check one of your two pgpool services.